# Is there a way to react to a related list being changed in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, related-list, javascript-controller

Simply put, i need to make a lightning component, that depending on related objects to the one whose page i'm in, has different functionality. If the user creates a new related object via the related lists standard component, mine should react to it.

I've been reading on lightning events, but **"force:recordSaveSuccess"** doesn't seem to be fired while using the standard components in the page.

Is it posible to react to changes to the object and it's related lists being made by the standard components?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've found the event [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm). This event is fired when anything is changed EXCEPT deleting an object through the related lists.

With this tag we will be able to receive the event:

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.onRefreshView}"/>
```

And with this we can force update all standard components:

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

---

I'll update the answer if/when i find how to react to a deleted objects on related lists.