# Standard "Related List - Single" component fires refreshView event only in certain cases

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have three standard related list(Related list - single) components on Opportunity object Lightning page as below:

1. Related list for detail child custom object(Master detail relation with Opportunity)
2. Related list for lookup child custom object(lookup relation with Opportunity)
3. Related list for lookup child **standard object**(OpportunityLineItem).

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Why is it that only related list component for standard object firing `refreshView` event when a record is added or deleted but not for the custom object related lists?

My ultimate goal is to detect if something changed on the related list component then take necessary action.

Comment: Thanks again for the discussion on this last week. I wonder if "refreshView" is really even the right place for this hook. Although it's been used and suggested by others to detect Related List changes, it seems to me that if the vendor intended it to be used for this, it might be named differently. The official documentation states that this event can be used to refresh all components, including Related Lists. It does not say it will be raised *by* Related Lists to notify of changes. It seems the problem here may actually be use of undocumented behavior (just like our showToast workaround).

Comment: @shannon I agree. There should be a documented and reliable approach for handling changes from related list. I didn’t realize how common this scenario is until I ran into your question. I hope this question gathers some attention and there will be a better solution.

Comment: I suspect the real cause here isn't a difference in the related lists per se, but that mutating `OpportunityLineItem` also mutates the `Opportunity` - the fields `HasOpportunityLineItem` and `Amount` get updated.